# Javascript open window with new settings

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open a window from double clicking an icon on my desktop.

I would like the window to be a specific size with no menubar, no scrollbar etc.

here what my code looks like:

```
document.onload(openWin());

function openWin()
{
    document.open("index.htm","PoPuP", 'menubar=no, scrollbar=no, sizeable=no');
}
```

As soon the document loads, the page itself loads and then another.

Comment: `document.onload(openWin());` isn't valid JavaScript.  I assume you are looking for `window.onload = openWin;`

Answer (score 1):

You're being a bit redundant, in addition to improperly using `onload`.  You also should use `window` instead of `document` in these cases, as [`document.open` does not do what you think it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open).  Instead, [`window.open` is what you were looking for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open):

```
window.onload = function openWin() {
    window.open("index.htm","PoPuP", 'menubar=no, scrollbar=no, sizeable=no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So u want to open a site from a hyperlink on your desktop?
You can't do that with JavaScript? It should be done with C#.
If you want to open a url and open the page in a pop-up, you can do that by following my tutorial:

There are two ways to do this. You can add a TARGET="_blank" to the -tag, but this simply opens a new browser window that completely obscures the old one.

This may be what you want, but at other times a small window on top of the large browser window is much better. This small window is popularly known as a popup.

First the basic syntax of how to create a popup, then an explanation of the script, including a table of the most common arguments you can give to a popup and the problem of focusing.
Then a new way of adding popup behaviour to a link. This site uses the new system because it's much cleaner than the old one.
Finally some notes about writing content directly into the popup. This gives several problems, most importantly the confusion over exactly what the URL of the popup is.

To create a popup you'll need the following script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150,menubar=no, scrollbar=no, sizeable=no');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

Then, you link to it by:

```
<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')"
    >Link to popup</a>
```

Good luck!